# Keras function api, setting weight manually to a layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

In keras Sequential model, one can set weight directly using `set_weights` method.

```
model.layers[n].set_weights([your_wight])
```

However I am facing problem if I am trying to set weight to a layer using functional API.

Here is the code snippet:

```
emb = Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen)(merge_ip)
         #skipping some lines
         .
         .
emb.set_weights([some_weight_matrix])
```

This is throwing error that

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'set_weights'
```

which I think becouse `emb` is a Tensor object.

I am wondering how to set wight properly in my model

Comment: here how to incorporate the GENSIM model inside Keras https://stackoverflow.com/a/62747179/10375049

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the weights on Embedding layers you might add them to the constructor like this:

```py
from keras.layers import Embedding

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                            trainable=False)
```

https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html

Later then you can hand over `merge_ip`:

```
x = embedding_layer(merge_ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
embed_layer = Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen)
emp = embed_layer(merge_ip)

embed_layer.set_weights("...")
```